# different language in the bibliograhpy feature of word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, language, bibliography

I am looking for help concerning a university task. I am using Word 2007 (installed in a German version) and want to enter all the quotes/citations and books into the bibliography system of word.

The whole document is written in English, but unfortunately this automatic bibliography ends up being in a German format - meaning that instead of e.g. "edited by", I see "herausgegeben von"...

Does anyone know how to change the language in this case? I have also installed the English Language Pack for Office... but still can't find a way to make it use the English messages instead of the Germaon ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having the language pack installed is sufficient - you do not need to change the word language to English.

Go to `Verweise -> Quellen verwalten` and edit all resources and set the language to `English`. This should do the job.